# With Thymeleaf, can I use TemplateEngine with UrlTemplateResolver but stay in the current thread or keep the context?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to render a subfragment which goes through a **Spring MVC controller** and **not directly rendering a Thymeleaf view template**.

Is it possible to keep the context with all variables inside it? Somehow?

Right now I am using the templateEngine that is processing a URL using the `UrlTemplateResolver` without big luck.

```
return templateEngine.process(url, context); // context contains all variables I need
```

However, even when passing the context correctly as above, it is lost because an internal request been made which basically is handled by a new thread.

The only possibility to pass any data from the parent `processor` to the subview (controller) is via GET params but this is less than ideal for me since I have a lot of variables like `currentLanguages`, `currentCountries`, etc. that I need inside the fragments.

Is it possible to somehow render a Thymeleaf fragment by going first through a Spring MVC controller but keeping the original context? I completely understand why a new thread and real get request is required for non-local URLs but what about local ones?

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to achieve?  Are you trying to re-use a context that has variables already set?

Comment: I am buiding a CMS where every widget has a "controller" and a "view". In case when I use JSPs I use context.include("/call/to/controller"); to render widgets. For thymeleaf however it looks I cannot do something like that. I can render the widget in many ways but I dont find a way to pass the context with all variables, request attributes, session attributes and so on.

Comment: Offhand, I don’t see readily see support for that.  If I had a gun to my head, I’d consider using BeanUtils.copyProperties to store the context in a new variable.